# Scraping con Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scraping

Quiero obtener información de web y procesarla en Excel. Utilizo VBA para ello.
El código que uso es:

```
...
Range("B4")=doc.getElementsByClassName("exchange__header-data-price")(0).innerText
...
```

El dato que quiero es 14.797,1. El código de la página es:

```
...
<span class="exchange__header-data-price" data-json="ultimo">14.797,1</span>
...
```

No me da error pero tampoco devuelve ningún resultado.
Supongo que el problema está en

```
data-json="ultimo"
```

No sé como hacerlo. Os agradezco vuestra ayuda.
Saludos cordiales

Comment: Prueba a hacer un bucle por todos los que tengan la misma clase. O pudiera ser que está en un iframe. Hay varias posibilidades, quizás si incluyes la web sea más fácil